# Need to change Access Control of Published Items though api

Tags: smartsheet-api, smartsheet-c#-sdk-v2

In Smartsheet I have downloaded Published Items list from user management. Using this list I need to change the Access control  (Public/Organization) value through api. Please help. Thanks

Comment: What do the docs say about this scenario? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi @Kim Brandl thanks for your response. The document ( Published Items) have Id, Type, Owner ,Publish Type ,Access Control, Published Link etc. I have written C# code to iterate this list and trying to change Access control status, if it meet certain condition. In this scenario I cannot able to get access control of sheet. I can able to get sheet name ,row , column .

Comment: I'm going to provide an answer below, but in the future please try to follow best practices for [how to ask a good question](https://www.apinewbies.com/stack-overflow-101#ask-question) here on Stack Overflow. Specifically, your question should provide enough information (including code) to clearly show what is you're doing and where/how you're running into trouble. Merely describing your objective in a couple of sentences and expecting someone to write all the code for you isn't generally a very successful approach when seeking help here on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the type of object you're updating (`Sheet`, `Report`, or `Dashboard`), the operations you'll use are as follows:

- [Set Sheet Publish Status](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?csharp#set-sheet-publish-status)
- [Set Report Publish Status](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?csharp#set-report-publish-status)
- [Set Dashboad (Sight) Publish Status](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?csharp#set-dashboard-publish-status)

I've included some code examples below (taken nearly verbatim from those you'll find in the docs I've linked to above.)

One additional note: You'll notice that the values written to the Published Items list that you manually export from Smartsheet differ from the values used by the API. For example, the `Access Control` column of exported data contains values like `Organization` and `Public` -- where as the corresponding values used by the API are `ORG` and `ALL`.

**Example #1: SHEET --> Set ReadOnlyFullAccessibleBy to ALL, ReadWriteAccessibleBy to ORG**

```
SheetPublish sheetPublish = new SheetPublish();

sheetPublish.ReadOnlyLiteEnabled = false;
sheetPublish.ReadOnlyFullEnabled = true;
sheetPublish.ReadOnlyFullAccessibleBy = "ALL";
sheetPublish.ReadWriteEnabled = true;
sheetPublish.ReadWriteAccessibleBy = "ORG";
sheetPublish.IcalEnabled = false;

smartsheet.SheetResources.UpdatePublishStatus(
  4583614634583940,       // sheetId
  sheetPublish
);
```

**Example #2: Report --> Set ReadOnlyFullAccessibleBy to ORG**

```
ReportPublish reportPublish = new ReportPublish();

reportPublish.ReadOnlyFullEnabled = true;
reportPublish.ReadOnlyFullAccessibleBy = "ORG";

smartsheet.ReportResources.UpdatePublishStatus(
  1653087851556740,    // reportId
  reportPublish
);
```

**Example #3: Dashboard (Sight) --> Set ReadOnlyFullAccessibleBy to ALL**

```
SightPublish publish = new SightPublish();

publish.ReadOnlyFullEnabled = true;
publish.ReadOnlyFullAccessibleBy = "ALL";

smartsheet.SightResources.SetPublishStatus(
  5363568917931908,    // sightId
  publish
);
```